# Error Magento 2. PayPal Standard and Express does not work

Tags: magento, paypal

Magento 2.0.7 on Centos VPS managed server.
Throwing error when trying to make the payment is:

> security header is not valid (# 10002)

Both PayPal and Magento forums indicate that the error is due to errors password and / or key.

Indeed the error exists, but is not in writing. Magento 2 not properly stored credentials, as indicated in the post [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83019/paypal-admin-area-wont-save-api-details).

Whether credentials are erased as if they are changed, the same number of characters always appears.

I tried to erase the credentials, empty the cache and then return them to enter... but nothing.

I searched the table in which to store this data, but the tables related to PayPal:

```
paypal_billing_agreement, paypal_billing_agreement_order, paypal_cert, paypal_payment_transaction, paypal_settlement_report, paypal_settlement_report_row
```

None of these tables stores data related credentials Signature API, the table "cert" would store certificates exclusively.

Where credentials are stored PayPal? Is this a bug in Magento?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?